# Permission denied error with admin user while trying to create a grafana dashboard via API

Tags: python, request, authorization, grafana, grafana-api

I'm trying to migrate a couple of dashboards from one server to another. To accomplish this I write a pretty simple script using `python` and `requests` library.

```
class Grafana:
    def __init__(self, url, key):
        self.headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + key
            }
        self.url = url

    def get_all_dashboard_uris(self):
        return (dashboard['uri'] 
        for dashboard in requests.get(self.url+'api/search?query=', headers=self.headers
        ).json())

    def import_dashboard(self, dashboard_uri):
       return requests.get(self.url+'api/dashboards/'+dashboard_uri, headers=self.headers).json()['dashboard']

    def create_dashboard(self, dashboard_object):           
        dashboard_object['id'] = None #id = null to create a new dashboard 
        #(https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v4.1/http_api/dashboard/)
        return requests.post(self.url+'api/dashboards/db', headers=self.headers, json={'dashboard': dashboard_object})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initial_grafana = Grafana(url=URL, key=KEY)
    final_grafana = Grafana(url=URL_TEST, key=KEY_TEST)

    for dashboard_uri in initial_grafana.get_all_dashboard_uris():
        dash = initial_grafana.import_dashboard(dashboard_uri)
        print(dashboard_uri)
        result = final_grafana.create_dashboard(initial_grafana.import_dashboard(dashboard_uri))
        print(result.status_code, result.text)
        print('')
```

The problem is that this prints `403 {"message":"Permission denied"}` for all dashboards. I face this problem even if a try to create the dashboard with the exact same paramaters as the documentation suggests:

```
def create_test_dashboard(self):
        dashboard_object = {
            'dashboard': {
                'id': None,
                'title': 'Production Overview',
                'tags': ['templated'],
                'timezone': 'browser',
                'rows': [{}],
                'schemaVersion': 6,
                'version': 0
            },
            'overwrite': False
            }
        return requests.post(self.url+'api/dashboards/db', headers=self.headers, json=dashboard_object)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   final_grafana = Grafana(url=URL_TEST, key=KEY_TEST)
   result = final_grafana.create_test_dashboard()
```

Some quick notes that I think it's important:

1) I have no problem if I use the `import_dashboard` method in the `final_grafana` object;

2) No problem at all if I create the dashboard manually using a `.json` file;

3) I'm using an admin role user;

4) I'm using Grafana 4.2.

**Any ideas on how to solve this?**

Comment: Anything useful in Grafana logs (debug log level)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In fact, debug level didn't give me any extra information than info level: `t=2020-02-10T11:59:31-0300 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=27 uname= method=POST path=/api/dashboards/db status=403 remote_addr=xxxxxxx time_ms=86ns size=31`